# What does Heron's formula naturally deform?

Tags: combinatorics, euclidean-geometry, symmetric-groups, symmetric-polynomials, symmetric-functions

Fixing three real numbers $a,b,c>0$ determines a triangle with
side-lengths $a,b,c$ (if admissible). Therefore, the area of a
triangle is a function in $a,b,c$. Due to the geometry of a
triangle, we know that the area is a *symmetric function* in
$a,b,c$. Indeed, Heron formula shows that

$$area(a,b,c) = \frac{1}{4} \sqrt{[(a+b+c)] \cdot [(a+b-c)(a-b+c)(-a+b+c)]}$$

What's interesting is that the radicand is the product of two
symmetric polynomials. The fact that it's a product (and
therefore not as "pure") motivates me to look at the following
expression:

$$f(a,b,c,d) = (a+b+c-d)(a+b-c+d)(a-b+c+d)(-a+b+c+d)$$

Notice that $f$ is a symmetric polynomial, with $f(a,b,c,0)$
recovering the "impure" product.

**Question**: Does $f$ calculate anything? In other words, is
there any known combinatorial or geometrical meaning of $f$? I
will be glad to see if it deforms the area of a triangle in
some interesting way, but any interpretation is welcome.

Comment: The expression you are interested in is exactly the radicand in the following formula for the volume of a tetrahedron: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heron%27s_formula#Heron-type_formula_for_the_volume_of_a_tetrahedron It's worth noting that the a,b,c,d are not the edge lengths, which would have been quite convenient. Nonetheless, it is an interesting generalization of Heron's Formula.

Comment: Following the citation, this result is due to [William Kahan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_Kahan). You can find it [on page 17/31 here](https://people.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wkahan/VtetLang.pdf).

Comment: Fascinating! By the nature of that formula, one cannot take $d$ to zero alone. I'm still waiting to see if there's any other interpretation :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Another interpretation is that it is the radicand in [brahmagupta's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brahmagupta%27s_formula?wprov=sfla1) for the area for a cyclic quadrilateral.

Comment: This indeed deforms the area of the triangle by deforming the triangle to cyclic quadrilateral. Thank you!